# JS - setInterval runs for a single instance

Tags: javascript

I am sorry I know this is a repetitive question, but I cant seem to get this right for some reason.

```js
function timer() {
  console.log("OVER HERE")
};

window.setInterval(timer, 5000);
```

I believe this is a fairly easy example im trying to implement but it only runs once. Sorry again if i am missing an obvious detail or something.

[This is the results it generates after the 6th second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qOcg.png)

Comment: Your code is fine

Comment: are you using this function inside a loop?

Comment: ^^ No..
I am doing this in reactJs, this gets called every the component updates

Comment: Why is my question being associated with "What is the small blue circle in the Chrome console log?", i know what that is, thats not the problem, my problem is why is it running without the delay.

Comment: Your question literally says "it only runs once", your screenshot says otherwise, the linked question explains the confusing bit here. Nothing in there show that "it [is] running without the delay".